# Is it good taste to add new bonuses to challenge?

Tags: discussion, code-challenge

Is it good taste to add bonuses to a challenge so that new answers can compete? On [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28896/program-to-use-all-your-bandwidth), a really short answer was given by simply tying to programs together (I was thinking of calling "outsourcing the answer" on it, but it solved it so well I refrained.) **Can I add new bonuses to allow more answers?** It was solved to quickly that it was no fun, and it wouldn't break old answers, as it is just bonuses (although they may need to be modified to compete.) What do you think?

Comment: If you do, you should at least leave a comment on all existing answers to inform the participants that there are new points to be claimed (if they want to give it a try). Just adding the bonus quietly in hope that a new answer will beat the existing one, which didn't know about the bonus, is not a nice move. I'm not recommending it in general though, I don't really have an opinion on whether this is good etiquette or not. I'm just saying what the bare minimum is you should do if you decide to add the bonus.

Comment: I would generally avoid changing challenges after posting, but if it makes no difference to the scores of current answers and allows all current answers to stay I think that it would be fine.